# Count in Spring Data MongoDB repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I wonder if there's any mechanism to use `count` in Spring Data MongoDB repository with `@Query` annotation?
I would love to receive the number of documents that I have without having to get all of them.

Basically, the equivalent of this in Java:

```
db.test.find({"type":"foo"}).count
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For me this solutions works like a charm( using spring-data-mongodb 1.3.1.RELEASE ),
I just had the same problem atm and solved it like this(just a short snippet from my code at work):

```
@Query(value = "{'productDetails.productType': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}, 'sourceDescriptor': ?1}", count = true)
public Long countFetchedDocumentsForCategory(String cat, String sourceDescriptor);
```

Comment: spring-data-mongodb:1.4.1.RELEASE also asks from adding in @Param annotation on parameters

Comment: I think You will endup. with 2 calls. find + count

Answer (score 68):

Another way to do this using MongoRepository query templates:

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyClass, String> {
    Long countByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for providing the doc; I've been working off of this for too long: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem recently and unfortunately did not find any solution at least not with current stable version. It seems that [it is possible](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-231) in Spring Data JPA 1.4M1 so maybe it will be also included in next version of Spring Data MongoDB.

Comment: Well, lest´s see if really happens. Thanks for the response!