# Is there a way to use @Query to return a MongoDB $sum result?

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

I'm pretty new to both MongoDB and StackOverflow (as a questioner). I've seen a great response for how to return a MongoDB "count" projection from a Spring repository using the @Query annotation ([Count in Spring data mongodb repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715010/count-in-spring-data-mongodb-repository)).

Basically the count example looks like:
@Query(value = "{'productDetails.productType': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}, 'sourceDescriptor': ?1}", count = true)

...and the method returns an int. I want to do a similar thing, but the int I return is a sum rather than a count. The @Query annotation doesn't look like it was built to support a sum() operation, but that's what I need.

I fear that I'm hosed and I have to iterate over a collection of documents to get to the result I need.

I have a collection of transactions (like debits and credits, positive and negative amounts). Here's a simulation of the transaction data:

[{ "action" : "AWARD", "amount" : 9000, "notes" : "Initial balance", "username" : "aa" },
{ "action" : "PAYOUT", "amount" : 1800, "notes" : "Earnings", "username" : "aa" },
{ "action" : "WITHDRAWAL", "amount" : -5000, "notes" : "Direct deposit /r#e#d#a#c#t#e#d/", "username" : "aa" },
{ "action" : "AWARD", "amount" : 7000, "notes" : "Initial balance", "username" : "bb" }]

I want to get the net (sum) of the various transactions for a given username, using a repository. And if possible I'd rather not return a list of all the Mongo documents and iterate over them to get the sum.

Is there a way to do this using the @Query annotation?

This is my first question. Please forgive me if I'm off target.

Comment: I want to be as helpful as possible... this is what I am trying to replicate in the Spring repository: db.accountTxns.aggregate([{$match:{username:'aa'}}, {$group:{_id:'$username', total: {$sum:'$amount'}}}])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmm, I think @Query annotation could not accomplish mongo aggregation (if I'm not wrong query and aggregate are different kind of operations) :(

You'll probably have to create your custom method and implement it by using Fluent Interfaces Spring comes with, for example if you want the $sum, the aggregation would look like:

```
TypedAggregation<YourClass.class> agg = newAggregation(YourClass.class,
   group("username").sum("amount").as("totalAmount"),
   project("totalAmount"));

AggregationResults<YourResultClassContainingOnlyTotalAmount> result =
   mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, YourResultClassContainingOnlyTotalAmount.class)
```

I hope it'is helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks Fernando... since it's my first post, I can't offer and votes for your answer yet. I'm hoping to do it with a straight repository, though I've already found reasons to create a Spring CustomRepository for other areas of the codebase.

Comment: No problem :-) I'm happy to share a few knowhow