# Length in query spring-data

Tags: sql, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

i'm working spring-boot and spring-boot data
is there any way to check length of data from MongoDB

```
@Query("SELECT * from branch where LENGTH(code) = 5")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715010/count-in-spring-data-mongodb-repository

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Query

```
@Query("{$expr:{$eq:[{$strLenCP: '$code' },5]}}")
```