# Spring mongodb count all documents in collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to create method to count all documents in collection using @query

For example

```
@query("db.collection.count()")
Long countAllDocuments;
```

Comment: I found maybe dumb solution but still... Using Long countAllWhereUuidIsNotNull();. So I count all documents where id is not null, i.e. every of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think the folowing code should hep you :

```
@Query(value = "{}", count = true)
public Long countAllDocuments();
```

Similar issue : [Count in Spring Data MongoDB repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715010/count-in-spring-data-mongodb-repository)